# PHP OOP class construct inheritance

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I am trying to understand one PHP OOP concept, lets say i have two classes A and B. B extends A there fore A is Base/Parent class. If class A has a __construct class B will automatically inherit it...?

Example:

```
class Car 
{

    public $model;
    public $price;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = 'BMW';
        $this->price = '29,00,00';
    }

}

class Engine extends Car
{
    parent::__construct();
}
```

By `parent::__construct();` class Engine will execute `Car __construct();` automatically?

But I always though if I inherit from parent class the `__construct` will be executed automatically anyway why would I add this `parent::__construct()`?

Comment: [RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Comment: The subclass should be like this: `function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
   }`

Comment: @Thamizhan The subclass should be like ***this***: `class Engine extends Car {}`. No need to override a method just to call its parent's implementation; simply omit it entirely.

Comment: `Engine` is not a `Car`.. It's a `Car Component`..

Comment: @Thamizhan so hold on guys so if I simply extend the parent class, the child class will automatically execute parent class __construct when I instantiate child class....? or Do i have to add in my Child class parent::__construct...? or makes no difference and it does what are the benefits of either...?

Comment: @Tomazi yes.. if the child class has no constructor then the parent constructor will be automatically called.. if you set a constructor to the child class then you must explicitly call `parent::__construct()` only if you need so..

Comment: @Tomazi so if you want to change the order of execution of parent constructor, you can use parent call inside the sub class constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When one class `extends` another, it inherits all its methods. Yes, that includes the constructor. You can simply do `class Engine extends Car {}`, and `Engine` will have a constructor and all other properties and methods defined in `Car` (unless they're `private`, which we'll ignore here).

If you define a method of the same name as already exists in `Car` in `Engine`, you're *overriding* that method implementation. That's exactly what it sounds like: *instead of* `Car`'s implementation, `Engine`'s method is called.

> why would I add this `parent::__construct()`?

If you're *overriding* a method, yet you *also* want to call the parent's implementation. E.g.:

```
class Engine extends Car {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        echo 'Something extra';
    }
}
```

Comment: OK las question  so I guess I can override any method I wish not only __construct, if I had a method openDoor in Car class and wanted to override it in Engine class how would I do that...?

Comment: ...exactly the same way...?! `class Engine extends Car { public function openDoor() {} }`

Comment: BTW, I hope this starts to show what [@Matei](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34589919/php-oop-class-construct-inheritance/34590114?noredirect=1#comment56924881_34589919) was saying in the comments... An `Engine` with an `openDoor` method...!? That makes no sense. The relationship between an engine and a car is not one of inheritance, your `Engine` should not `extend` your `Car`. They're two different, independent classes. Your `Car` should have a property `$engine` which is an instance of `Engine`, if anything.

Comment: I agree I just written a quick example now looking at it I agree it makes no sense for engine to extend car xD. well Thx now I have a better picture of this idea will go and test it out now :)

Answer (score 0):

Overriding a constructor in a child class is exactly that, **overriding**... you're setting a new constructor for the child to **replace** the parent constructor because you want it to do something different, and generally you won't want it to call the parent constructor as well..... that's why you need to explicitly call the parent constructor from the child constructor if you want them both to be executed.

If you don't create a child constructor, then you're not overriding the parent constructor, so the parent constructor will then be executed